# Python: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python

I have a list with a single string that contains non-ascii characters. My goal is to get rid of the non-ascii characters and convert the list to a string.

Every time I try to strip out the non-ascii characters, I get this error: `'list' object has no attribute 'read'`

I've tried most of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638893/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-in-python-to-convert-a-string-to-all-lowercase-str#answer-639325) and I still get this error every time. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show some code, we aren't psychic.

Comment: not even code really. Just your input and expected output would suffice. I can tell you right now though that you're passing something a list when you should be passing it a file. Unless you're actually trying to call `read` on a list...

Answer (score 2):

Py3:

```
thelist[0].encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
```

this works for python 2.x:

```
import string
filter(lambda c:c in string.printable, thelist[0])
```

Comment: Why do you mark your first bit as Python 3? It works fine in Python 2.6.

Comment: @kabie: `printable` is a **subset** of `ascii`; you are throwing away more data than the OP intends.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Throw an error on my Python 2.6.  @John Machin: You are right. should be like "filter(curses.ascii.isascii, thelist[0])"

Comment: @Kabie: `u'f\x81oo\xf1bar'.encode('ascii','ignore').decode() == u'foobar'`

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Because you are using a unicode string, which is the default string in py3. 'f\x81oo\xf1bar'.encode('ascii','ignore').decode() will not work.

Comment: @Kable: very well then, if you're assuming you're starting with a `str`, `str(unicode(thelist[0], 'ascii', 'ignore'))` will do.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: which is not working on py3. But good enough for py2.x.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ''.join([s.encode('ascii','ignore') for s in mylist])
```

Comment: This is converting `unicode` to `str` (py2) or `str` to `bytes` (py3) ... probably not what the OP expects.

Comment: @Hugh, your answer inspired this u''.join(mylist).encode('ascii', 'ignore')  not addressing @John here, just thinking about the idea of u''.join().

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to activate the virtaulenv

From this way it worked!