# How to change long gene names to abbreviated in some automatic way (microarray data processing)?

Tags: bioinformatics, data-processing, genome

Is there any automatic way to convert a list of long gene names (like Cadherin_3453) to its abbreviations, like CDHRN_3453?
Are there any abbreviation name convention in Genomics, Bioinformatics?

Sorry, no code herein

Answer (score 0):

There is the [HUGO database](http://www.genenames.org/) which tries to standardize gene names. Depending on your use case you can either try to access their online search every time or [download the data](http://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/hgnc_downloads) and use your own database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post a programming language that you want, I am guessing that this is just a simple, one-time exercise that you would like to do.

Though it is not a true abbreviation, you could just remove all of the vowels in the gene name (as you may have done by accident in your example).

You should use:

http://www.togglecase.com/convert_to_disemvowelled_text.php

It was able to change `Cadherin_3453` to `Cdhrn_3453`.

If you a looking to be able to do this with a program that you can tailor to your specific needs, you can look into this SO question: [String replace vowels in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301292/string-replace-vowels-in-python)