# transpose dictionary (extract all the values for one key from a list of dictionaries)

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
 data = [{'x': 1, 'y': 10},
         {'x': 3, 'y': 15},
         {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
          ... ]
```

I have a function (for example `matplotlib.axis.plot`) which needs lists of `x` and `y` values. So I have to "transpose" the dictionary".

First question: what do you call this operation? Is "transpose" the correct term?

I've tried this, but I'm searching for an efficient way (maybe there are some special `numpy` function):

```
x = range(100)
y = reversed(range(100))
d = [dict((('x',xx), ('y', yy))) for (xx, yy) in zip(x,y)]
# d is [{'y': 99, 'x': 0}, {'y': 98, 'x': 1}, ... ]

timeit.Timer("[dd['x'] for dd in d]", "from __main__ import d").timeit()
# 6.803985118865967

from operator import itemgetter
timeit.Timer("map(itemgetter('x'), d)", "from __main__ import d, itemgetter").timeit()
# 7.322326898574829

timeit.Timer("map(f, d)", "from __main__ import d, itemgetter; f=itemgetter('x')").timeit()
# 7.098556041717529

# quite dangerous
timeit.Timer("[dd.values()[1] for dd in d]", "from __main__ import d").timeit()
# 19.358459949493408
```

Is there a better solution? My doubt is: in these cases the hash of the string `'x'`is recomputed every time?

Comment: Should that be `from operator import itemgetter` ?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, string hashes are calculated only once and stored in [`s->ob_shash`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a2ef447b80d/Objects/stringobject.c#l1258) for reuse.

Comment: Have you considered changing to a dictionary of lists instead of a list of dictionaries?  Then your data access would be `d['x'][idx]` instead of `d[idx]['x']`, but that doesn't seem too difficult to switch ... (it will also probably be more memory efficient)

Comment: @mgilson: I can't, it comes from the output of a database query

Comment: Can you change the database query?

Comment: Also keep in mind that timeit runs each operation one million times, so even the slowest one is only taking 0.02 milliseconds per operation

Comment: @grieve: I'm using an API to access to data on a remote database, so no, I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing the form from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/639325/34329)

```
import timeit
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap

x = range(100)
y = reversed(range(100))
d = [dict((('x',xx), ('y', yy))) for (xx, yy) in zip(x,y)]
# d is [{'y': 99, 'x': 0}, {'y': 98, 'x': 1}, ... ]
D={x:y for x,y in zip(range(10),reversed(range(10)))}


def test_list_comp(d):
    return [dd['x'] for dd in d]

def test_list_comp_v2(d):
    return [(x["x"], x["y"]) for x in d]

def testD_keys_values(d):
    return d.keys()

def test_map(d):
    return map(itemgetter('x'), d)

def test_positional(d):
    return [dd.values()[1] for dd in d]

def test_lambda(d):
    return list(imap(lambda x: x['x'], d))

def test_imap_iter(d):
    return list(imap(itemgetter('x'), d))

for test in sorted(globals()):
    if test.startswith("test_"):
        print "%30s : %s" % (test, timeit.Timer("f(d)", 
              "from __main__ import %s as f, d" % test).timeit())
for test in sorted(globals()):
    if test.startswith("testD_"):
        print "%30s : %s" % (test, timeit.Timer("f(D)", 
              "from __main__ import %s as f, D" % test).timeit())
```

Gives the following results:

```
    test_imap_iter : 8.98246016151
       test_lambda : 15.028239837
    test_list_comp : 5.53205787458
 test_list_comp_v2 : 12.1928668102
          test_map : 6.38402269826
   test_positional : 20.2046790578
 testD_keys_values : 0.305969839705
```

Clearly the biggest win is getting your data in a format closer to what you already need, but you may not control that.

As far as the name goes I would call it a transformation.

Comment: why did you add `testD_keys_values`? I'm surprised for the difference between `test_map` and `test_list_comp`

Comment: @wiso: Re testD_keys_values: Someone posted that as an answer, and then deleted it. I would guess test_map is slower, because itemgetter is returning a function (or technically a callable) that is slightly more expensive than getting the attribute directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to iterate over the values you can consider this method:

```
imap(lambda x: x['x'], d)
```

Comment: I doubt that this will perform better than any of the methods OP has already described ...

Comment: it seems you're the winner: 0.2664310932159424

Comment: @wiso: I don't think that 0.27s value is a fair comparison.  That's the time to construct the imap object, not the time to actually extract all the data.  If you wrap it in a `list` to make it equivalent, it's pretty slow.

Comment: @wiso I didn't measure it before posting, I just thought you might gain something memory-wise by using itertools.

Comment: @wiso: a lot of that is `lambda` overhead.  If you use `itemgetter('x')` instead it should be closer to the others (but still probably slower.)

Comment: @DSM: it's still slower, if I substitute `lambda` with `itemgetter` I get 9.2505

Comment: @zenpoy , I am getting `name 'imap' is not defined`. Something missing in my installation?

Comment: @wander95 , just import the function 'from itertools import imap'

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
[(x["x"], x["y"]) for x in d]
```

that will return a list of tuples containing the x and y position. I'm not sure about the speed of it, but it will get rid of the lambda overhead.