# Is there a way to make collections.Counter (Python2.7) aware that its input list is sorted?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, counter

## The Problem

I've been playing around with different ways (in Python 2.7) to extract a list of (word, frequency) tuples from a corpus, or list of strings, and comparing their efficiency. As far as I can tell, in the normal case with an unsorted list, the `Counter`method from the `collections` module is superior to anything I've come up with or found elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to take much advantage of the benefits of a pre-sorted list and I've come up with methods that beat it easily in this special case. So, in short, is there any built-in way to inform `Counter` of the fact that a list is already sorted to further speed it up?

(The next section is on unsorted lists where Counter works magic; you may want to skip to towards the end where it looses its charm when dealing with sorted lists.)

## Unsorted input lists

### One approach that doesn't work

The naive approach would be to use `sorted([(word, corpus.count(word)) for word in set(corpus)])`, but that one reliably gets you into runtime problems as soon as your corpus is a few thousand items long - not surprisingly since you're running through the entire list of n words m many times, where m is the number of unique words.

### Sorting the list + local search

So what I tried to do instead before I found `Counter` was make sure that all searches are strictly local by first sorting the input list (I also have to remove digits and punctuation marks and convert all entries into lower case to avoid duplicates like 'foo', 'Foo', and 'foo:').

```py
#Natural Language Toolkit, for access to corpus; any other source for a long text will do, though.
import nltk 

# nltk corpora come as a class of their own, as I udnerstand it presenting to the
# outside as a unique list but underlyingly represented as several lists, with no more
# than one ever loaded into memory at any one time, which is good for memory issues 
# but rather not so for speed so let's disable this special feature by converting it
# back into a conventional list:
corpus = list(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words()) 

import string
drop = string.punctuation+string.digits  

def wordcount5(corpus, Case=False, lower=False, StrippedSorted=False):
    '''function for extracting word frequencies out of a corpus. Returns an alphabetic list
    of tuples consisting of words contained in the corpus with their frequencies.  
    Default is case-insensitive, but if you need separate entries for upper and lower case 
    spellings of the same words, set option Case=True. If your input list is already sorted
    and stripped of punctuation marks/digits and/or all lower case, you can accelerate the 
    operation by a factor of 5 or so by declaring so through the options "Sorted" and "lower".'''
    # you can ignore the following 6 lines for now, they're only relevant with a pre-processed input list
    if lower or Case:
        if StrippedSorted:
            sortedc = corpus 
        else:    
            sortedc = sorted([word.replace('--',' ').strip(drop)
                   for word in sorted(corpus)])
    # here we sort and purge the input list in the default case:
    else:
            sortedc = sorted([word.lower().replace('--',' ').strip(drop)
                   for word in sorted(corpus)])
    # start iterating over the (sorted) input list:
    scindex = 0
    # create a list:
    freqs = []
    # identify the first token:
    currentword = sortedc[0]
    length = len(sortedc)
    while scindex < length:
        wordcount = 0
        # increment a local counter while the tokens == currentword
        while scindex < length and sortedc[scindex] == currentword:
            scindex += 1
            wordcount += 1
        # store the current word and final score when a) a new word appears or
        # b) the end of the list is reached
        freqs.append((currentword, wordcount))
        # if a): update currentword with the current token
        if scindex < length:
            currentword = sortedc[scindex]
    return freqs
```

### Finding `collections.Counter`

This is much better, but still not quite as fast as using the Counter class from the collections module, which creates a dictionary of {word: frequency of word} entries (we still have to do the same stripping and lowering, but no sorting):

```py
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for word in [token.lower().strip(drop) for token in corpus]:
    cnt[word] += 1
# optionally, if we want to have the same output format as before,
# we can do the following which negligibly adds in runtime:
wordfreqs = sorted([(word, cnt[word]) for word in cnt])
```

On the Gutenberg corpus with appr. 2 million entries, the Counter method is roughly 30% faster on my machine (5 seconds as opposed to 7.2), which is mostly explained through the sorting routine which eats around 2.1 seconds (if you don't have and don't want to install the nltk package (Natural Language Toolkit) which offers access to this corpus, any other adequately long text appropriately split into a list of strings at word level will show you the same.)

### Comparing performance

With my idiosyncratic method of timing using the tautology as a conditional to delay execution, this gives us for the counter method:

```py
import time
>>> if 1:
...     start = time.time()
...     cnt = Counter()
...     for word in [token.lower().strip(drop) for token in corpus if token not in [" ", ""]]:
...         cnt[word] += 1
...     time.time()-start
...     cntgbfreqs = sorted([(word, cnt[word]) for word in cnt])
...     time.time()-start
... 
4.999882936477661
5.191655874252319
```

(We see that the last step, that of formatting the results as a list of tuples, takes up less than 5% of the total time.)

Compared to my function:

```py
>>> if 1:
...     start = time.time()
...     gbfreqs = wordcount5(corpus)
...     time.time()-start
... 
7.261770963668823
```

## Sorted input lists - when `Counter` 'fails'

However, as you may have noticed, my function allows to specify that the input is already sorted, stripped of punctuational garbage, and converted to lowercase. If we already have created such a converted version of the list for some other operations, using it (and declaring so) can very much speed up the operation of my `wordcount5`:

```py
>>> sorted_corpus = sorted([token.lower().strip(drop) for token in corpus if token not in [" ", ""]])
>>> if 1:
...     start = time.time()
...     strippedgbfreqs2 = wordcount5(sorted_corpus, lower=True, StrippedSorted=True)
...     time.time()-start
... 
0.9050078392028809
```

Here, we've reduced runtime by a factor of appr. 8 by not having to sort the corpus and convert the items. Of course the latter is also true when feeding `Counter` with this new list, so expectably it's also a bit faster, but it doesn't seem to take advantage of the fact that it is sorted and now takes twice as long as my function where it was 30% faster before:

```py
>>> if 1:
...     start = time.time()
...     cnt = Counter()
...     for word in sorted_corpus:
...         cnt[word] += 1
...     time.time()-start
...     strippedgbfreqs = [(word, cnt[word])for word in cnt]
...     time.time()-start
... 
1.9455058574676514
2.0096349716186523
```

Of course, we can use the same logic I used in `wordcount5` - incrementing a local counter until we run into a new word and only then storing the last word with the current state of the counter, and resetting the counter to 0 for the next word - only using `Counter` as storage, but the inherent efficiency of the `Counter` method seems lost, and performance is within the range of my function's for creating a dictionary, with the extra burden of converting to a list of tuples now looking more troublesome than it used to when we were processing the raw corpus:

```py
>>> def countertest():
...     start = time.time()
...     sortedcnt = Counter()
...     c = 0
...     length = len(sorted_corpus)
...     while c < length:
...         wcount = 0
...         word = sorted_corpus[c]
...         while c < length and sorted_corpus[c] == word:
...             wcount+=1
...             c+=1
...         sortedcnt[word] = wcount
...         if c < length:
...             word = sorted_corpus[c]
...     print time.time()-start
...     return sorted([(word, sortedcnt[word]) for word in sortedcnt])
...     print time.time()-start
... 
>>> strippedbgcnt = countertest()
0.920727014542
1.08029007912
```

(The similarity of the results is not really surprising since we're in effect disabling `Counter`'s own methods and abusing it as a store for values obtained with the very same methodology as before.)

Therefore, my question: Is there a more idiomatic way to inform `Counter` that its input list is already sorted and to make it thus keep the current key in memory rather than looking it up anew every time it - predictably - encounters the next token of the same word? In other words, **is it possible to improve performance on a pre-sorted list further by combining the inherent efficiency of the `Counter`/`dictionary` class with the obvious benefits of a sorted list**, or am I already scratching on a hard limit with .9 seconds for tallying a list of 2M entries?

There probably isn't a whole lot of room for improvement - I get times of around .55 seconds when doing the simplest thing I can think of that still requires iterating through the same list and checking each individual value, and .25 for `set(corpus)` without a count, but maybe there's some itertools magic out there that would help to get close to those figures?

(Note: I'm a relative novice to Python and to programming in general, so excuse if I've missed something obvious.)

### Edit Dec. 1:

Another thing, besides the sorting itself, which makes all of my methods above slow, is converting every single one of 2M strings into lowercase and stripping them of whatever punctuation or digits they may include. I have tried before to shortcut that by counting the unprocessed strings and only then converting the results and removing duplicates while adding up their counts, but I must have done something wrong for it made things ever so slightly slower. I therefore reverted to the previous versions, converting everything in the raw corpus, and now can't quite reconstruct what I did there.

If I try it now, I do get an improvement from converting the strings last. I'm still doing it by looping over a list (of results). What I did was write a couple of functions that would between them convert the keys in the output of J.F. Sebastian's winning default_dict method (of format `[("word", int), ("Word", int)], ("word2", int),...]`) into lowercase and strip them of punctuation, and collapse the counts for all keys that were left identical after that operation (code below). The advantage is that we're now handling a list of roughly 50k entries as opposed to the > 2M in the corpus. This way I'm now at 1.25 seconds for going from the corpus (as a list) to a case insensitive word count ignoring punctuation marks on my machine, down from about 4.5 with the Counter method and string conversion as a first step. But maybe there's a dictionary-based method for what I'm doing in `sum_sorted()` as well?

**Code:**

```py
def striplast(resultlist, lower_or_Case=False):
    """function for string conversion of the output of any of the `count_words*` methods"""
    if lower_or_Case:
        strippedresult = sorted([(entry[0].strip(drop), entry[1]) for entry in resultlist])
    else:
        strippedresult = sorted([(entry[0].lower().strip(drop), entry[1]) for entry in resultlist])
    strippedresult = sum_sorted(strippedresult)
    return strippedresult

def sum_sorted(inputlist):
    """function for collapsing the counts of entries left identical by striplast()"""
    ilindex = 0
    freqs = []
    currentword = inputlist[0][0]
    length = len(inputlist)
    while ilindex < length:
        wordcount = 0
        while ilindex < length and inputlist[ilindex][0] == currentword:
            wordcount += inputlist[ilindex][1]
            ilindex += 1
        if currentword not in ["", " "]:
            freqs.append((currentword, wordcount))
        if ilindex < length and inputlist[ilindex][0] > currentword:
            currentword = inputlist[ilindex][0]
    return freqs

def count_words_defaultdict2(words, loc=False): 
    """modified version of J.F. Sebastian's winning method, added a final step collapsing
    the counts for words identical except for punctuation and digits and case (for the 
    latter, unless you specify that you're interested in a case-sensitive count by setting
    l(ower_)o(r_)c(ase) to True) by means of striplast()."""
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for w in words:
        d[w] += 1
    if col=True:
        return striplast(sorted(d.items()), lower_or_case=True)
    else:
        return striplast(sorted(d.items()))
```

I made some first attempts at using groupy to do the job currently done by `sum_sorted()`, and/or `striplast()`, but I couldn't quite work out how to trick it into summing `[entry[1]]` for a list of entries in `count_words`' results sorted by `entry[0]`. The closest I got was:

```py
# "i(n)p(ut)list", toylist for testing purposes:

list(groupby(sorted([(entry[0].lower().strip(drop), entry[1]) for entry in  iplist])))

# returns:

[(('a', 1), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb290>), (('a', 2), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb250>), (('a', 3), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb210>), (('a', 5), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb2d0>), (('a', 8), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb310>), (('b', 3), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb350>), (('b', 7), <itertools._grouper object at 0x1031bb390>)]

# So what I used instead for striplast() is based on list comprehension:

list(sorted([(entry[0].lower().strip(drop), entry[1]) for entry in  iplist]))

# returns:

[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('a', 5), ('a', 8), ('b', 3), ('b', 7)]
```

Comment: FWIW, there's invalid & incorrect code in your **Edit Dec. 1** section. Specifically, in the `count_words_defaultdict2()` function definition near the end there's `if col=True:`, which is both a `SyntaxError` and I believe you meant to refer to the argument `loc`, not `col`.

Comment: Following up on my previous comment: You could just eliminate the `if`/`else` at the end altogether and use `return striplast(sorted(d.items()), lower_or_case=loc)`.

Answer (score 7):

Given a sorted list of words as you mention, have you tried the traditional Pythonic approach of `itertools.groupby`?

```
from itertools import groupby
some_data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
count = dict( (k, sum(1 for i in v)) for k, v in groupby(some_data) ) # or
count = {k:sum(1 for i in v) for k, v in groupby(some_data)}
# {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: I really need to read into itertools, it's still largely magic spells to me. So, thanks! It reduces time by about a third (down to .62 seconds in my case) on the sorted input list. On the unpreprocesssed one, Counter wins, though. What I tried was to emulate the on-the-fly processing I've been doing before with my own function and Counter, by replacing your line with `count = {k:sum(1 for i in v) for k, v in groupby((token.lower().strip(drop) for token in some_data))}`

Comment: `len(list(v))` is [slightly faster than `sum(1 for _ in v)` for corpus/gutenberg input on my machine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13656047/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `len(tuple(v))` is faster yet (0.30 usec vs. 0.35 usec for `len(list(v))` on my machine, Python 2.7.3), as tuples are more compact and easier to construct.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question from the title: Counter, dict, defaultdict, OrderedDict are hash-based types: to look up an item they compute a hash for a key and use it to get the item. They even support keys that have no defined order as long as they are hashable i.e., Counter can't take advantage of pre-sorted input.

The measurements show that the sorting of input words takes longer than to count the words using dictionary-based approach and to sort the result combined:

```
sorted                  3.19
count_words_Counter     2.88
count_words_defaultdict 2.45
count_words_dict        2.58
count_words_groupby     3.44
count_words_groupby_sum 3.52
```

Also the counting of words in already sorted input with `groupby()` takes only fraction of the time it takes to sort the input in the first place and faster than dict-based approaches.

```
def count_words_Counter(words):
    return sorted(Counter(words).items())

def count_words_groupby(words):
    return [(w, len(list(gr))) for w, gr in groupby(sorted(words))]

def count_words_groupby_sum(words):
    return [(w, sum(1 for _ in gr)) for w, gr in groupby(sorted(words))]

def count_words_defaultdict(words):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for w in words:
        d[w] += 1
    return sorted(d.items())

def count_words_dict(words):
    d = {}
    for w in words:
        try:
            d[w] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[w] = 1
    return sorted(d.items())

def _count_words_freqdist(words):
    # note: .items() returns words sorted by word frequency (descreasing order)
    #       (same as `Counter.most_common()`)
    #       so the code sorts twice (the second time in lexicographical order)
    return sorted(nltk.FreqDist(words).items())
```

To reproduce the results, [run this code](https://gist.github.com/4180407/54b8a2b406051bdb419d3f6df124fa79e3aed06d).

Note: It is 3 times faster if nltk's lazy sequence of words is converted to a list (`WORDS = list(nltk.corpus.gutenberg.words())` but relative performance is the same:

```
sorted                  1.22
count_words_Counter     0.86
count_words_defaultdict 0.48
count_words_dict        0.54
count_words_groupby     1.49
count_words_groupby_sum 1.55
```

The results are similar to [Python - Is a dictionary slow to find frequency of each character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522152/python-is-a-dictionary-slow-to-find-frequency-of-each-character).

If you want to normalize the words (remove punctuation, make them lowercase, etc); see answers to [What is the most efficient way in Python to convert a string to all lowercase stripping out all non-ascii alpha characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638893/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-in-python-to-convert-a-string-to-all-lowercase-st). Some examples:

```
def toascii_letter_lower_genexpr(s, _letter_set=ascii_lowercase):
    """
    >>> toascii_letter_lower_genexpr("ABC,-.!def")
    'abcdef'
    """
    return ''.join(c for c in s.lower() if c in _letter_set)

def toascii_letter_lower_genexpr_set(s, _letter_set=set(ascii_lowercase)):
    return ''.join(c for c in s.lower() if c in _letter_set)

def toascii_letter_lower_translate(s,
    table=maketrans(ascii_letters, ascii_lowercase * 2),
    deletechars=''.join(set(maketrans('', '')) - set(ascii_letters))):
    return s.translate(table, deletechars)

def toascii_letter_lower_filter(s, _letter_set=set(ascii_letters)):
    return filter(_letter_set.__contains__, s).lower()
```

To count and normalize the words simultaneously:

```
def combine_counts(items):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for word, count in items:
        d[word] += count
    return d.iteritems()

def clean_words_in_items(clean_word, items):
    return ((clean_word(word), count) for word, count in items)

def normalize_count_words(words):
    """Normalize then count words."""
    return count_words_defaultdict(imap(toascii_letter_lower_translate, words))

def count_normalize_words(words):
    """Count then normalize words."""
    freqs = count_words_defaultdict(words)
    freqs = clean_words_in_items(toascii_letter_lower_translate, freqs)
    return sorted(combine_counts(freqs))
```

[Results](https://gist.github.com/4180407/f1667f7d2304d5d1d3e749c4aef330b5ecc3522c)

I've updated the benchmark to measure various combinations of `count_words*()` and `toascii*()` functions (5x4 pairs not shown):

```
toascii_letter_lower_filter      0.954 usec small
toascii_letter_lower_genexpr     2.44 usec small
toascii_letter_lower_genexpr_set 2.19 usec small
toascii_letter_lower_translate   0.633 usec small

toascii_letter_lower_filter      124 usec random 2000
toascii_letter_lower_genexpr     197 usec random 2000
toascii_letter_lower_genexpr_set 121 usec random 2000
toascii_letter_lower_translate   7.73 usec random 2000

sorted                  1.28 sec 
count_words_Counter     941 msec 
count_words_defaultdict 501 msec 
count_words_dict        571 msec 
count_words_groupby     1.56 sec 
count_words_groupby_sum 1.64 sec 

count_normalize_words 622 msec 
normalize_count_words 2.18 sec
```

The fastest methods:

- normalize words - `toascii_letter_lower_translate()`
- count words (presorted input) - `groupby()`-based approach
- count words - `count_words_defaultdict()`
- it is faster first to count the words and then to normalize them - `count_normalize_words()`

Latest version of the code: [count-words-performance.py](https://gist.github.com/4180407/#file_count_words_performance.py).

Comment: Good call, and I did realize that sorting is (one of) the slow part(s) of my method. I was still interested in what would be the best method _assuming_ you have a pre-sorted list.

Comment: Another slow part of my method is that it picks out every string to convert to lowercase and strip of punctuation before counting. I edited my question to reflect my attempts at delaying that step, although in real life it might be more realistic to have a pre-converted corpus already handy (for purposes like finding contexts for words, where you also want to ignore case) than a sorted one, the latter being useless other than for counting.

Answer (score 0):

One source of inefficiency in the OP's code (which several  answers fixed without commenting on) is the over-reliance on intermediate lists. There is no reason to create a temporary list of millions of words just to iterate over them, when a generator will do.

So instead of

```
cnt = Counter()
for word in [token.lower().strip(drop) for token in corpus]:
    cnt[word] += 1
```

it should be just

```
cnt = Counter(token.lower().strip(drop) for token in corpus)
```

And if you really want to sort the word counts alphabetically (what on earth for?), replace this

```
wordfreqs = sorted([(word, cnt[word]) for word in cnt])
```

with this:

```
wordfreqs = sorted(cnt.items())   # In Python 2: cnt.iteritems()
```

This should remove much of the inefficiency around the use of `Counter` (or any dictionary class used in a similar way).