# How to count the number of 1D arrays in a 2D array (Python)?

Tags: python, list, numpy

If I have a numpy 2D array, say:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How do I count the number of instances of [1, 2, 3] in a? (The answer I'm looking for is 2 in this case)

Comment: @SeanPianka not a duplicate, the OP is asking about numpy arrays

Comment: @SeanPianka: Not a duplicate of that question, since lists and arrays behave differently. Might be a duplicate of some other question, though.

Comment: It is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python

Comment: @wsun88: `a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]]` is not what a NumPy array looks like. That line would produce a list. The differences between lists and arrays matter; be aware of which type you're using.

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't really know how to represent numpy arrays, so I just represented it as a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the counts of *all* the arrays you could use [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]])
uniques, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True, axis=0)
print([(unique, count) for unique, count in zip(uniques, counts)])
```

**Output**

```
[(array([1, 2, 3]), 2), (array([2, 3, 4]), 1), (array([3, 4, 5]), 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you said it's a `numpy` array, rather than a list, you can do something like:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]])
>>> sum((a == [1,2,3]).all(1))
2
```

`(a == [1,2,3]).all(1)` gives you a boolean array or where all the values in the row match `[1,2,3]`: `array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)`, and the sum of that is the count of all `True` values in there