# How to count occurances of multiple items in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the folowing numpy array:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2]
```

I want to `count([1,2])` to count all occurrences of 1 and 2, in a single run, yielding something like

```
[4, 5]
```

corresponding to a `[1, 2]` input.

Is it supported in numpy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28663910/4940954 Could you do something like this? This will give you the counts of each number.

Comment: yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: Use `np.bincount(a)[[1, 2]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Setting your input to an array
array = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2])

# Find the unique elements and get their counts
unique, counts = np.unique(array, return_counts=True)

# Setting the numbers to get counts for as a set
search = {1, 2}

# Gets the counts for the elements in search
search_counts = [counts[i] for i, x in enumerate(unique) if x in search]
```

This will output [4, 5]