# Numpy search an element in array(scatter and reduce)

Tags: python, numpy, mpi4py

I'm trying in this code to search a given element into an array that has random numbers. With scatter and reduce i want just to count how many times the element exists in the array. I scatter the array and the searching  is being done in the splitting sub-arrays. Every splitting array finds how many times the element is found in this sub-array and then with reduce i gather all the times that the element is found in the whole primary array.

Comment: I think the line  `a=comm.bcast(a,root=0) ` shouldn't be there (?)

Comment: I think recvbuf is 2-dimensional array size of [1,N/nprocs] and you trying to compare array of size N/nprocs with single value in line recvbuf[i]==b. May be you need 1-dimesnional array of size N/nprocs here

Comment: This line is for the broadcast of the array to the other ranks. The primary array obtained random elements only on rank 0 and this is the reason you have to broadcast the array in order the other ranks be informed of the elements of the array.

Comment: If i make the recvbuf 1-d :recvbuf= np.empty ([N/nprocs], dtype=np.int)
........................i have these faults:
 File "search.py", line 29, in <module>
    if(recvbuf[i]==b):
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 29, in <module>
    if(recvbuf[i]==b):
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50

Comment: I meant I don't see the point in using *both* bcast and Scatter. Either use one or the other, no?

Answer (score 1):

The error is triggered because `recv_buf.shape` is `(1,N//nprocs)`.

Make it 1-D `recvbuf= np.empty ([N//nprocs], 'd')`, and it will be ok  (note my use of `//`, so your program works for both py2 and py3).

By the way, you may want to look at this to count occurences:
[How to count the occurrence of certain item in an ndarray in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python)

Also, you're mixing different types: `a` on process zero is not typed (so it is int64), `a` on the other processes is typed 'i' (so it is int32, but you don't use it so it's a real issue), and recvbuf is 'f' (float32).

Comment: If i make the recvbuf 1-d :recvbuf= np.empty ([N/nprocs], dtype=np.int) ........................i have these faults: File "search.py", line 29, in <module> if(recvbuf[i]==b): IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50 Traceback (most recent call last): File "search.py", line 29, in <module> if(recvbuf[i]==b): IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50

Comment: That's simply your `(N/nprocs)+1` that shouldn't have the +1 (you should double check the integer division rounding with a few examples to be 100% sure)

Comment: You typed `recvbuf` as 'd' (float), so if you print it, you'll see it doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: First: ', array([ 7, 67, 11, 50, 69, 15, 16, 73, 35, 92, 21,  6, 37, 22, 28, 38, 72,
       56, 51, 73, 20,  9, 28, 53, 96,  8, 94, 66, 62, 73, 52, 77, 37,  0,
       43, 25, 34, 86, 47,  0, 65, 83, 67, 29, 47, 41, 39, 62, 61, 44, 75,
       24, 66, 76, 42, 64, 16, 42,  2, 23, 10, 18,  0, 94, 43, 38, 47, 22,
       95,  6, 74, 48,  2, 35, 33, 93, 66, 76, 63, 86, 80, 30, 93, 12, 85,
       25,  2, 90, 91, 30, 40, 16, 46, 42, 74, 19, 71, 60, 80, 67]))
('The element 20 found:', 0)

although b=20 exists on the array...why this happens??

Comment: You're really mixing many different types: `a`on process zero is not typed (so it is int64), `a`on the other processes is typed 'i' (so it is int32), and `recvbuf` is 'f'  (float32).