# Counting number of specific numbers in the column of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

I have a question, which is probably very simple to solve but I just couldn't find an answer.
I want to count the number of the values 0, 1 and 2 in the column of a numpy array. My array has two columns, and I want to count the values 0, 1 and 2 in the second column. I tried to solve this like this:

```
   for row in vergleich[:,1]:
       n = vergleich[:,1].count(0)
       o = vergleich[:,1].count(1)
       t = vergleich[:,1].count(2)
       print(n)
       print(o)
       print(t)
```

But I get the error message : AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'
What are other ways to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can use `np.count_nonzero(<condition on array>)` to count. example: `np.count_nonzero(a==0)`

Comment: your loop seems to be not necessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the occurrence of certain item in an ndarray in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python)

Comment: Check out the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

Run: `np.count_nonzero(vergleich[:,1] == 0)`, the same for other numbers of interest.

Another, more general alternative:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(vergleich[:,1], return_counts=True)
result = dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

Then *result* will contain *key* / *value* pairs:

- *key* - value in your column,
- *value* - how many times it occurred.

So then you may query *result* for keys *0*, *1* and *2*.

**Yet another option**, but this time based on *Pandas*:

Run: `res = pd.value_counts(vergleich[:,1])`

The result is a *Pandas* *Series* with:

- index - a value in the source *Series* (a *Numpy* 1-D array can also
  be passed),
- value - how many times it occurred.