# How to speed up counting the elements in a NumPy array with function other than map and list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data file (temp.dat) that consists of 3 columns and ~20k rows. It looks like this:

```
0 1 100.00
0 2 100.00
0 3 100.00
...
1 10 100.00
1 11 100.00
1 12 100.00
1 13 100.00
1 14 100.00
1 15 100.00
1 16 100.00
1 17 100.00
...
0 10 100.00
0 11 100.00
0 12 100.00
...
```

I would like to count the number of rows that satisfy the following criteria in the code. I tried map and list comprehension but both seem incredible slow. List comprehension is about a minute faster.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('temp.dat')
base1, base2, pct = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]
expected_count = 10000

BASE_NAME = []
for x in range(0,36):
    count1 = sum(map(lambda base1 : base1 == x, base1)) 
    count2 = sum(map(lambda base2 : base2 == x, base2))
    total_count = count1 + count2
    if total_count == expected_count:
        base_num = x
        BASE_NAME.append(base_num)

total_base_name = len(BASE_NAME)
print (total_base_name)
```

For list comprehension, the syntax becomes:

```
count1 = sum([base1 == x for base1 in base1])
count2 = sum([base2 == x for base2 in base2])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the occurrence of certain item in an ndarray in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray-in-python)

Comment: Partially, as i ended up using numpy count_nonzero in the end.

Answer (score 2):

(**EDITED**: I somewhat overlooked that you were using NumPy arrays)

To replace:

```
sum(map(lambda base1 : base1 == x, base1))
```

or:

```
count1 = sum([base1 == x for base1 in base1])
```

the best approach depends if your input is a `list` or a NumPy array.

- if you have a `list`, you could use the [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method:

```
base1.count(x)
```

- if you have a NumPy array, as this seems to be the case, you could use [`np.count_nonzero()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) for NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy as np


np.count_nonzero(base1 == x)
```

However, this will create a potentially large temporary object.
This can be solved by creating your own function and accelerate it with [Cython](https://cython.org/) (not shown) or, even better, with [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), as shown below:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.jit
def nb_count_equal(arr, value):
    result = 0
    for x in arr:
        if x == value:
            result += 1
    return result
```

which would also be faster than `np.count_nonzero()` in this case.

Testing some of these approaches on toy data shows that they give the same result:

```
np.random.seed(0)  # to ensure reproducible results

arr = np.random.randint(0, 20, 1000)
y = 10

print(sum(map(lambda x: x == y, arr)))
# 41
print(sum([x == y for x in arr]))
# 41
print(np.count_nonzero(arr == y))
# 41
print(nb_count_equal(arr, y))
# 41
```

with the following timing:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 20, 1000000)
y = 10

%timeit sum(map(lambda x: x == y, arr))
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.54 s per loop
%timeit sum([x == y for x in arr])
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.43 s per loop
%timeit np.count_nonzero(arr == y)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 574 µs per loop
%timeit nb_count_equal(arr, y)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 224 µs per loop
```

---

Note, the previous suggestion of removing the square brackets to avoid creating a temporary list is slower than just having a generator because of the way `sum()` is implemented, but it would definitely have the advantage of avoiding to create unnecessary temporary lists.

---

Finally, if you are doing this counting multiple times, it may be more beneficial to do this in a single go with [`np.unique()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Comment: @hamster Sorry I have overlooked that you were using NumPy arrays, check out the updated answer.

Comment: numba isn't an option as I have to use a remote cluster computer to do the processing. It isn't installed. I tested with np.unique and count_nonzero and both are running a lot faster for looping 36 times with 20k row per input file. I'll ask if i have anymore question.