# numpy matrix count distinct

Tags: python, numpy

Assume there is a numpy contains the following data structure:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([['2','W','A'],
             ['3', 'R', 'A'],
             ['4', 'W', 'R'],
             ['2', 'E', 'R'],
             ['4', 'E', 'Y'],
             ['3', 'E', 'Y']])
```

1. Need to summarize the appearance number of unique instances in the third column and return numpy so that it returns the following result:

```
[['A' '2']
 ['R' '2']
 ['Y' '2']]
```

(For example the value of `A` appears in the third column twice, so the result will be `'A' '2'`.)

2. Similarly, sum the unique values found in both the second and third columns and return numpy in the following structure:

```
[['W' 'A' '1']
 ['R' 'A' '1']
 ['W' 'R' '1']
 ['E' 'R' '1']
 ['E' 'Y' '2']
```

For example the value of `E` in the second column together with the value of `Y` in the third column appears twice, so the result will be `'E' 'Y' '2'`.

Comment: It's interesting that you want the number of instances but in string format.

Comment: Maybe it's me but can you make explicit what you mean by "appearance number of unique instances"?

Comment: Sorry ... there was a data error, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, you can use `np.unique()`, and specify `axis = 0` to tabulate the rows:

```
def tabulate_array(x,columns):
    idx,counts = np.unique(x[:,columns],return_counts=True,axis=0)
    return [list(idx[i]) + list(str(counts[i])) for i in range(len(counts))]
```

The last part to concatenate the counts and list might be refined a bit more but for now it will give you the string output, for example:

```
tabulate_array(a,[2])
[['A', '2'], ['R', '2'], ['Y', '2']]

tabulate_array(a,[1,2])
[['E', 'R', '1'],
 ['E', 'Y', '2'],
 ['R', 'A', '1'],
 ['W', 'A', '1'],
 ['W', 'R', '1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

(setup code)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
   [['2', 'W', 'A'],
   ['3', 'R', 'A'],
   ['4', 'W', 'R'],
   ['2', 'E', 'R'],
   ['4', 'E', 'Y'],
   ['3', 'E', 'Y']],    
)
```

Pandas is well suited for this and leverages numpy on the backend.  For example, you can get the second, third column counts like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)    
cols = [1,2]
df[cols].value_counts().astype("str").reset_index().values
```

result:

```
array([['E', 'Y', '2'],
       ['W', 'R', '1'],
       ['W', 'A', '1'],
       ['R', 'A', '1'],
       ['E', 'R', '1']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's [count occurances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray), then reformat

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([['2','W','A'],
             ['3', 'R', 'A'],
             ['4', 'W', 'R'],
             ['2', 'E', 'R'],
             ['4', 'E', 'Y'],
             ['3', 'E', 'Y']])

unique, counts = np.unique(a[:, 2], return_counts=True)
result = np.vstack([unique, counts]).T
print(result)
```

---

As for the second qurstion:
If you want to avoid for loops or list comprehensions, and stick to plain numpy, and are willing to give up your exact formatting for the output, you can do

```
ind_col = np.core.defchararray.add(a[:, 1], a[:, 2])
unique, counts = np.unique(ind_col, return_counts=True)
result1 = np.vstack([unique, counts]).T

print(result1)
```

> ```
> [['ER' '1']
>  ['EY' '2']
>  ['RA' '1']
>  ['WA' '1']
>  ['WR' '1']]
> ```