# Count unique register in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with letters `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`,

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array(["a", "a", "c", "c", "a"]) # In this example "b" is not present
```

I want to fuild a function `f` that counts the unique records of each letter present in the array, for my example `f` should respond `[3, 0, 2]` meaning that `"a"` has appeared 3 times, `"b"` 0 times and `"c"` 2 times.

I'm looking for solution (if it possible) that use numpy functions and not explicit for loops over the array. Maybe a kind of group by

Comment: Wihat is a typical size of the array `my_array`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-to-count-the-occurrence-of-certain-item-in-an-ndarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the collections builtin will do that for you.

```
import numpy as np 
my_array = np.array(["a", "a", "c", "c", "a"])
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(my_array)
cnt 
#  Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2})
```

Note that it does not provide counts for items which did not appear ***until*** you ask for them. At that point the counter will return 0.

```
>>> cnt['b']
0
```

If you want to wrap that in a function where you already have a list of keys (not all of which may be present in your array data), that ***will not populate*** the 0 counts with keys for you. If you want the 0s and the keys to be populated, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from typing import Dict, Any


def counter_function(data, keys) -> Dict[Any, int]:
    cnt = Counter(data)
    for key in keys:
        cnt[key] = cnt[key]
    return cnt

my_array = np.array(["a", "a", "c", "c", "a"])
so_counter = counter_function(my_array, ["a", "b", "c"])
so_counter
# Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 0})
```

will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `np.unique` with `return_counts=True`, and just convert it to a dict with `dict` + `zip`:

```
dct = dict(zip(*np.unique(my_array, return_counts=True)))
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{'a': 3, 'c': 2}
```

For smaller arrays, Lucas's answer is faster, but for large arrays, numpy is much more efficient.

Comment: This method does not handle the `0` key counts by default and the `collections.Counter` approach does even if it does not store the `0`s in the structure. The `dict` will raise a `KeyError` for `0` key counts.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that the OP wanted that. Good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If `my_array` has a typical length of about 10 or more, it can be worthwhile to convert your array to the integers [0, 1, 2] and then apply [`bincount()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

Here's an example with your `my_array`:

```
In [31]: my_array = np.array(["a", "a", "c", "c", "a"])

In [32]: b = my_array.view(np.int32) - ord('a')

In [33]: b
Out[33]: array([0, 0, 2, 2, 0], dtype=int32)

In [34]: np.bincount(b, minlength=3)
Out[34]: array([3, 0, 2])
```

Here's a timing comparison of that method and `collections.Counter` using an input with length 100:

```
In [34]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [35]: a = rng.choice(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], size=100)

In [36]: %timeit Counter(a)
32.1 µs ± 723 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit b = a.view(np.int32) - ord('a'); np.bincount(b, minlength=3)
3.86 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The approach with `bincount()` is much faster.

It is also faster than using `np.unique()` with the parameter `return_counts=True`:

```
In [41]: %timeit values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
19.7 µs ± 274 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks Warren this is a nice solution-and fast! The question asked for handling of `0`s for specific keys and this ***does not*** handle that case, unless I'm mistaken? The `collections.Counter` approach will but it does not store the `0` values. If storing the `0`s is required then I think you need to pass keys and store similar to how I've done.

Comment: The question says *'I have a numpy array with letters "a", "b" or "c"...'*, but then qualifies that by saying that a letter (e.g. `"b"`) might be missing.  The code in my answer handles that correctly, and you can see that for the given example, `my_array`, it returns exactly what the OP asked for, `[3, 0, 2]`.  It is certainly possible that @Andrex has a more general problem in mind, and the description in the question doesn't reflect the full generality. If that is the case, @Andrex should probably update the question.