# Generate counts along axis in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, array-broadcasting

I am wondering if there is a numpy way to do the following with multiple axes:

Desired Input:

```
np.array([[1,2,3],
          [4,5,5]])
```

Desired Output:

```
np.array([[0,1,1,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,1,2]])
```

The 2 in the second row of the second array indicates that 2 5s were present in the second row of the first array.

If not, I will just have to iterate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the occurrence of a certain item in an ndarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-do-i-count-the-occurrence-of-a-certain-item-in-an-ndarray)

Comment: Iterate over the rows with `np.bincount`.  If `a` is the input array, something like `m = np.max(a) + 1; result = np.array([np.bincount(row, minlength=m) for row in a])`

Comment: Can you explain how that input turned into that output?

Comment: @Pranav columns in the output are the counts of 1 to 5, by row

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` the input and using broadcasting:

```
out = (a[...,None] == np.arange(np.max(a)+1)).sum(axis=1)
```

Or with a loop and [`bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) as suggested in comments:

```
N = a.max()+1
out = np.array([np.bincount(x, minlength=N) for x in a])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `pandas`:

```
(pd.concat(
    [x.value_counts(sort=False) for _,x in pd.DataFrame(a).iterrows()], axis=1)
 .reindex(range(np.max(a)+1)).fillna(0).T.astype(int).values)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]])
```