Numpy Unique - how to make array with counts?
So, basically, I have a txt file like this:

I read it and this is my code:
name_k, let_k = np.loadtxt(path + 'known_mass_period.txt', skiprows = 1, unpack = True, usecols = (0,1), dtype = str)

m_k, p_k = np.loadtxt(path + 'known_mass_period.txt', skiprows = 1, unpack = True, usecols = (2,3))

name_k, let_k, m_k, p_k = name_k[m_k>0], let_k[m_k>0], m_k[m_k>0], p_k[m_k>0]

names, ind, xx, n = np.unique(name_k, return_index = True, return_inverse = True, return_counts = True)

Now, I have names that gives me the unique values, ind gives me the indices of the array, xx is the full array with indices, and n is how many times each name appears. What I need to do is to make an additional array with the values in n repeated for each time it appears. For instance, the first name is 14Her which appears twice, and then 47UMa appears 3 times, so I need an array like new_n = [2, 2, 3, 3, 3] (and so on for all the names). How do I do this with the arrays obtained with np.unique()?

you can group you columns by name and perform aggregation using count.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-do-i-count-the-occurrence-of-a-certain-item-in-an-ndarray

Which of the answers in that post are you referring to?

Will the identical star names always be grouped together in the file? For example, if you had ["14Her", "47UMa", "14Her", "47UMa", "47UMa"], would you want the new_n array to contain [2, 3, 2, 3, 3], or will this never happen?

Yes, they will always be grouped together

How about trying np.repeat?
new_n = np.repeat(n, n)

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Ok so the main problem was that np.unique() automatically sorts the result, changing the initial order of my elements. The best way I've found to solve the issue is with
names = names[np.argsort(ind)]
n = n[np.argsort(ind)]

new_n = np.repeat(n, n)


You can use the 'np.repeat' function, which repeats elements of an array, to repeat the values in n according to their respective counts in the xx array.
create the new_n array:
new_n = np.repeat(n, n)

print(new_n)


n is an array where each element represents the count of occurrences of the corresponding unique name.

np.repeat(n, n) repeats each element in n according to its own value. This means if n[i] is 2, it will repeat the value 2 exactly 2 times, and so on.


